# How to get started on c++ library

Tags: std

I just finished learning some advance c++ concept, and I can't really apply those knowledge to build anything I can think of, within getting to know the c++ Library well.
 So that I can know which classes and library to use.. So my question is how can I learn and know the library classes or header in need for my projects, and if there are other library witch I can learn, or just have to learn the standard library alone for now... Am sorry if this question sounds silly,  I just need an answer and will be very greatful if I can get a really good, helping answer here.. Thats in advance

Comment: You could fill a shelf with [books on the subject](https://www.aristeia.com/books.html).

Comment: That's a super broad question.  Since you don't have a clear goal, you might consider gradually going through the standard library documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header).  To start, don't worry about learning every single detail, just familiarize yourself with which data structures and algorithms are available.  That being said, if you have a particular problem that you want to solve, then you can look for a library that solves your particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It been long overdue for an answer, The Standard Template Library (STL) is a set of C++ template classes to provide common programming data structures and functions such as lists, stacks, arrays, etc. It is a library of container classes, algorithms, and iterators.

STL has four components

```
 1. Algorithms
 2. Containers
 3. Functions
 4. Iterators
```

Algorithms are collection of functions especially designed to be used on ranges of elements examples are `Sorting Searching` etc

Containers or container classes store objects and data. There are in total seven standard container classes examples are `vector list deque arrays`

The STL includes classes that overload the function call operator. Instances of such classes are called function objects or `functors`.

As the name suggests, iterators are used for working upon a sequence of values. They are the major feature that allow generality in STL. `Iterators`
`

Below links are references to understand more:

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/
2. [http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/stl/headers.html](http://cs.stmarys.ca/%7Eporter/csc/ref/stl/headers.html)
3. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/
4. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-c-standard-template-library-stl/